# Enumerate image files from a directory

Tags: .net, image, directory, enumeration, file-type

I would like to get a list of all image files in a given folder.

```
Dim targetFolder As String = "C:\Data\"    
Dim imagefiles = From file In Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetFolder)

For Each f In imagefiles
    'do something
Next
```

The above lists however all file types. How to change it to return only image file types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image files could have multiple extensions, but EnumerateFiles could take only one extension in its overload. You could overcome this limitation providing a list of file extensions and using the IEnumerable methods Where and Any

```
Dim targetFolder As String = "C:\Data"    
Dim imgExtensions() As string  = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png" }
Dim imageFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetFolder) _ 
                 .Where(Function(s) imgExtensions _
                 .Any(Function(x) x = Path.GetExtension(s)))

For Each file in imageFiles
    Console.WriteLine(file)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a second parameter to `Directory.EnumerateFiles`:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetFolder, "*.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second parameter to `Directory.EnumerateFiles` that is a search pattern:

```
Dim targetFolder As String = "C:\Data\"    
Dim imagefiles = From file In Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetFolder, "*.jpg")

For Each f In imagefiles
    'do something
Next
```

This will enumerate all files that end in .jpg. However, there is no definite list of "all image files". You will need to define that yourself in a search pattern that makes sense to your application.

Comment: If I have my images files as Dim extensions() As String = {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".jpe", ".jfif", ".png"}, how do I enumerate those?

Comment: @user2143213, have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039580/multiple-file-extensions-searchpattern-for-system-io-directory-getfiles

Comment: There is already an answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/how-to-filter-directory-enumeratefiles-with-multiple-criteria