# Filter a directory for .csv files using c# lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

Help me improve the lambda below with adding another conditon like

Get me all .csv with no matching .wav file. Example, say "sample.csv" and "sample.wav", then I dont want to collect "sample.csv".

```
Files = new DirectoryInfo(txtStartPath.Text)
           .EnumerateFiles("*.csv")
           .Where(file => file.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-ageOfFile))
           .ToList();
```

Comment: see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203

Comment: no it is not what i was looking for, I want the resulting list with .csv that dont have a matching .wav in the same directory (assume no sub directory)

Comment: You say only get `.csv` from directories that does not have `.wav` files in same dir? OR get only `.csv`s that does not have `.wav` with same name on the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get list of `wav` files first:

```
var wavFiles = new DirectoryInfo(txtStartPath.Text)
                   .EnumerateFiles("*.wav")
                   .Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
                   .ToList();
```

and then you can use it as part of `Where` condition:

```
Files = new DirectoryInfo(txtStartPath.Text)
           .EnumerateFiles("*.csv")
           .Where(f => f.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-ageOfFile))
           .Where(f => !wacFiles.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)))
           .ToList();
```