# How to get the files within a directory using a date range?

Tags: c#

The possible solution I've thought of is like this:

```
var dateFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filesPath)
    .Where(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date >= startDate && 
                new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date <= endDate);
```

I'm new to the `=>` syntax and I'm not sure how to put `new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date` into a *variable* so I don't have to initialize it *twice*. Also, let me know if there's a more optimal solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the problem with your query? Did you try to debug it? If you create a breakpoint you can have a look in the different properties

Comment: Query looks fine for me. What are your `startDate` and `endDate` values?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. It might work. I'm just wondering how I can not use "new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date" twice. Instead, just put it inside a variable and use it. Confused about the syntax.

Comment: Use a select just before your where^^

Comment: `Select` is your friend :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332868/filter-a-directory-for-csv-files-using-c-sharp-lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's add `Select` where we turn `fileName` into an *anonymous type* instance in which we can store *both* `name` and `date`:

```
var dateFiles = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(filesPath)               
  .Select(fileName => new {                // given fileName   
     name = fileName,                      // store name  
     date = new FileInfo(fileName).CreationTime.Date // ... and date
   })
  .Where(file => file.date >= startDate && // filter by date
                 file.date <= endDate)
  .Select(file => file.name);              // finally, we want name only
```

Please, notice `EnumerateFiles`: we don't want to wait whne all the files be collected but ready to process file after file.

Comment: you have a typo - `file.date >= endDate` should be `file.date <= endDate`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DirectoryInfo` instead of `Directory`, and that will return an array of `FileInfo` (vs the array of strings you get from the `Directory.GetFiles` method):

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(filesPath);
var dateFiles = directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()
                .Where(x => x.CreationTime.Date >= startDate && x.CreationTime.Date <= endDate)
                .Select(f => f.Name);
```

Comment: Nice idea to start from `DirectoryInfo` and get `CreationTime` with `Name` for free

Answer (score 1):

I would do someting compact like this:

```cs
DateTime start = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*")
       .Where(
          f => new FileInfo(f).CreationTime.Date >= start && 
               new FileInfo(f).CreationTime.Date <= end
        ).ToArray();
```

Comment: GeFile provides a filter option that might come handy like Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.cs")

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your lambda expression in your `Where` into a statement body:

```
 var dateFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(x =>
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(x);
            return fileInfo.CreationTime.Date >= startDate && 
                   fileInfo.CreationTime.Date <= endDate
        });
```