# Directory.EnumerateFiles with "special" filters

Tags: c#, .net, directory, file-extension

I need to filter some files in a directory.  I have to filter diferent kind of files with diferent extensions, but one is "??b" . Example
29389.99b or 382802.03b. For the other files it works fine but how can I filter this?
I´m using

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".??b") || s.EndsWith(".in") || s.EndsWith(".txt"));
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this posting as well as do a simple google search on the following `Directory.EnumerateFiles() Method` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/how-to-filter-directory-enumeratefiles-with-multiple-criteria  also see if there is a `s.Contains` method that you can use on the lambda statement

Comment: you could also look at something like this for example 
`var resultFileNames = (from fileInfo in new DirectoryInfo(@path).GetFiles(".??b") select fileInfo.Name).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check extension length and last letter.

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s =>
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(s);
        return ext.Length == 4 && ext.EndsWith("b")
            || s.EndsWith(".in")
            || s.EndsWith(".txt");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may solve it using regex. The following code can help you.

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"(.*)\.+.{2}b$"));
```

Comment: `\w` not match, for example, `-`. Pattern may be much more simple: `@"\...b$"`

Comment: Code tested on .net 4.5 project. The code is working.

Comment: `\w` pattern not include all allowable path characters.

Comment: Yes it is true. I corrected the expression. Now '.' pattern include all allowable path characters.