# bring multi extension files and stop looping them when the list reach the end - c#

Tags: c#, listview, directory, getfiles, filelist

i have a simple software that loop ***multi*** `Images/videos`
and show them ***one by one*** using (`Next`)-(`previous`) buttons

so far i success bring only one extension in a time using :

```
string[] FileList = Directory.GetFiles(Dir, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

and i tried stop looping when the list reach the End by using this code :

```
int currentPosition = 0;
if (currentPosition != ImageList.Length) currentPosition++;
```

excuse my mistakes cause i still Noob in c# but when I debug its says
`> IndexOutOfRangeException`

and after i add multi Extensions like this :

```
    string[] VOut_AVI = Directory.GetFiles(@Curr_DirectoryName, "*.avi", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    string[] VOut_MP4 = Directory.GetFiles(@Curr_DirectoryName, "*.mp4", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    string AddMP4 = VOut_MP4[VOut_MP4.Length - 1];
    //------ Adding other format to our call ------------
    Array.Resize(ref VOut_AVI, VOut_AVI.Length + 1);
    VOut_AVI[VOut_AVI.Length - 1] = AddMP4;

    // just for test ----->>
    MessageBox.Show("Video link : " + VOut_AVI[currentPosition]);
```

i get this error said (`XamlParserException`) for that one .

if you know easy way to get multi extensions without 
using that much of coding like i did i'll be happy to know it
also my looping process as you saw not that good if you can guide me to the right way , i'm still learning those things its a bit hard for me cause i come from a completely different environment , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of filenames with different extensions use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and concat these queries.

```
IEnumerable<string> myFilesQuery = new string[] { };

myFilesQuery = myFilesQuery.Concat( Directory.EnumerateFiles( dir, "*.avi", SearchOption.AllDirectories ) );
myFilesQuery = myFilesQuery.Concat( Directory.EnumerateFiles( dir, "*.mp4", SearchOption.AllDirectories ) );
myFilesQuery = myFilesQuery.Concat( Directory.EnumerateFiles( dir, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories ) );

// nothing will happen until we call

IList<string> myFiles = myFilesQuery.ToList( );
```

If you like to have a one-line-of-code for your code, write a helper like

```
public static class DirectoryHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles( 
        string path, 
        SearchOption searchOption, 
        params string[] searchPatterns )
    {
        if ( searchPatterns == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( searchPatterns ) );

        IEnumerable<string> result = new string[] { };

        foreach ( var searchPattern in searchPatterns )
        {
            result = result.Concat( Directory.EnumerateFiles( path, searchPattern, searchOption ) );
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and inside our code you have only

```
IList<string> myFiles 
    = DirectoryHelper
        .EnumerateFiles( 
            dir, 
            SearchOption.AllDirectories, 
            "*.avi", "*.mp4", "*.jpg" )
        .ToList();
```

You do not have to worry about any length of an array. The list will have the number of containing elements in the `Count` property.

All collections are are zero-based and the first item has index 0 and the last item has index `Count-1` (collection) or `Length-1` (array). You reach the end when `currentPosition >= mylist.Count-1` and you can increase the index as long as `currentPosition < mylist.Count-1`.

**Update**

There is already an answer here on SO dealing with multiple search patterns with a parallel implementation

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3754470/1744164

Comment: This code runs perfect with Visual Studio 2015ff. Change nameof( searchPatterns ) to a string "searchPatterns"

Comment: I already gave you the answer: list use myFiles.Count, array use myFiles.Length. And you should read the docs => google search for "c# IList" will lead you to MSDN

Comment: thanks :) and how about sort my files by **date created**  ?
i google it but they way much complicated from what i want and it didn't work with my code up there .
i just want **simple code** to sort my files **by date** .

Comment: look for FileInfo and IEnumerable.OrderBy

Comment: BTW do you know Visual Studio Community Edition? It is nearly the Pro edition (far away from being limited) and free for a wide range of developers and you can get VS2013/2015 or the brand new 2017RC as CE

Comment: yes i know them but like VS 2013 require 5 GB or more on C: Drive (without allowing you to change it to other drive) and my C: drive have Left only 11 GB space . 11 - 5 = not enough space for windows to run smoothly , so i work on old version till i get new Hard Drive .
Anyway : i figure out this code here : 
`var orderedFiles = new DirectoryInfo(Dir).GetFiles("*.jpg")
                                                        .OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToList();` but how to add **Multi Extensions** to this Order? and I thank you in Advance for all the help you give here

Comment: Well, in exactly the same way you did with Directory ... do you remeber Directory.GetFiles and the method I point you to (Directory.EnumerateFiles). Now you use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles. Just guess what method I would point you now to. Got it? (DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles)

Comment: Is there a special point that keeps you away from reading the documentation of DirectoryInfo? The method list is ordered from a..z and all Enumerate... methods are listed before the Get... methods.

Answer (score 0):

Length returns the number of items, but it will retrieved from index 0,1.

For example if your list total 2 records, then you can access the item in 0,1 index only. it's not availabe in 2nd index, hence it throws an error.

Change into `ImageList.Length-1`

To get all files with different extension you could use EnumerateFiles with extension type *. Also you can filtered the files using where clause.

```
var resufile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"fullpath", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mp4") || s.EndsWith(".jpg"));  //different extension you can specify it
```

Comment: @SUB-HDR is this your full code where you getting an error? Share the full code, so easy to explain, I can't find any button there

Comment: @SUB-HDR for ex: string[] arr = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" }; array item contains 3 values, so length will be 3. but the starting index of item in array is 0 and not 1. hence will access the item in array must be arr[0] = "tes1", arr[1] = "test2", arr[2]= "test3". if you accessing the item in arr[3] it throws an error. because arr doesn't contain index 3.

Comment: Use Directory.EnumerateFiles(...).Concat( Directory.EnumerateFiles(...)).ToList()

Comment: @BalajiMarimuthu : thank you very much for the explaint :)

Comment: @SirRufo ok thank you and how i set this code , like this maybe ? : Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\media").Concat( Directory.EnumerateFiles(".jpg",".png","mp4","avi")).ToList(‌​);