# How to use the DirectoryEnumerationFilters?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to create a small backup script in PowerShell but we have some long file names and deep folder so it's too much for get-childitems.
thats why i'm trying to use AlphaFS.

I wanna use the following but instead of "*" there is an overload where i can use DirectoryEnumerationFilters but i don't get how i can use them.
with the searchPattern i can only search for one file Extension.

```
Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries("D:\\Games", "*",
    System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I would like to get only the *.log and *.htm files in this example.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFileSystemEntries(string path,
    DirectoryEnumerationOptions options, DirectoryEnumerationFilters filters);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter Directory.EnumerateFiles with multiple criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/how-to-filter-directory-enumeratefiles-with-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Create a new `DirectoryEnumerationFilters` object and set its `InclusionFilter` property. It's a predicate (delegates) which accept a `FileSystemEntryInfo` and return a `bool` http://alphafs.alphaleonis.com/doc/2.2/api/html/A4BE4E7E.htm. You'd have to cast a script block to the delegate type or write some inline c# to create a class with a method that returns your delegate

Answer (score 0):

They have some sample code at https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS.

[C# example](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS/blob/master/AlphaFS.UnitTest/AlphaFS%20FileSystemEntryInfo%20Class/AlphaFS_Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntryInfos_EnumerateFiles_UsingDirectoryEnumerationFilters.cs)

[PowerShell example](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS/blob/master/PowerShell/Enumerate-FileSystemEntryInfos.ps1)

p.s. Perhaps you should add "AlphaFS" to the title.

Comment: Hey Shogun. You really need to provide some text in the answer rather than just link to answers. We do this in case links disappear over time as they often do

Answer (score 0):

Have taken a different approach:

```
if($job.Unterverzeichnisse -eq $true){ $SearchOption = "AllDirectories" }
else { $SearchOption = "TopDirectoryOnly" }

$AlphaFSDir::EnumerateFileSystemEntries($job.Pfade.Quelle, $SearchPattern, [System.IO.SearchOption]::$SearchOption) | % {
...
$FileName = $_
    if (($job.includes.include | % { $FileName -like $_}) -eq $true){
    ...
    }
}
```

`$job.includes.include` contains the extension i wanna use for this job.
each job has its own extensions - for example

1. job_1 = html
2. job_2 = csv,xls,xlsm