# Dynamically adding .EndsWith() from combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combo box called `comboFileTypes`.  Inside that is a drop down list containing:

```
MP4
MOV
MKV
VOB
```

And after a button press I have the following code to scan a directory for files:

```
var files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(sourceDIR.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => 
        s.EndsWith(".mp4") || 
        s.EndsWith(".mov") || 
        s.EndsWith(".vob") ||
        s.EndsWith(".MP4") || 
        s.EndsWith(".MOV") || 
        s.EndsWith(".VOB"));
```

Which is hardcoded.  I want the `WHERE` option to be dynamically generated from the combobox instead, so that the user can add another type of file if they need to. (Also case insensitive, if that's possible, otherwise I'll just add both cases)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want to scan for the selected item? or all items/fileendings in the combobox?

Comment: @MongZhu All files ending with the extensions listed in the combobox.  Currently they are hardcoded which is not what I want.

Comment: What's the role of combo box in the scenario? Use can just select a single item from `ComboBox`. May be you are talking about a multi-select listbox of a checkedlistbox? Or if it's a single combo box item, is it containing multiple extensions separated by | or something?

Comment: Anyway, use one of the solutions here: [How to filter Directory.EnumerateFiles with multiple criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3754118/3110834). You just need to get the extensions from somewhere, an item, selected items or .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get values from ComboBox by

```
var values = comboFileTypes.Items.Cast<string>()
```

and use it in like this:

```
var files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(sourceDIR.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => values.Any(v => s.EndsWith(v, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnorecase));
```

Comment: It looks good, but i'm getting an red underline on the `ComboBoxItem`, namespace could not be found?

Comment: Much better: `Where(s => values.Any(v => s.EndsWith(v, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnorecase));`. This also covers mixed-case file extensions like e.g. ".Mp4".

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, you're absolutely right! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe I'm missing something big, but...

```
void onOpen()
{
    var selected = comobFileTypes.SelectedItem;

    if ( selected != null ) {
        string ext = "." + selected.ToString();

        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDIR.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(
                s => s.EndsWith( ext );

        // ...more things...
    }

    return;
}
```

The key here is that **ComboBox** has a *SelectedItem* property, which can be `null` if  nothing is selected, or hold the selected option.

If you want to select all the extensions, then you can use the *Items* property.

```
void onOpen()
{
    string[] items = new string[ comboFileTypes.Items.Length ];

    foreach(int i = 0; i < items.Length; ++i) {
        items[ i ] = "." + comboFileTypes.Items[ i ].ToString();
    }

    var files = new List<string>();
    var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles( sourceDIR.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories );

    foreach(string ext in items) {
        files.AddRange( allFiles.Where( s => s.EndsWith( ext ) );
    }

    // ...more things... with files...
    return;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you - but that only adds the selected item in the combobox, I want all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Get all extensions from combobox:

```
 var extensions = comboFileTypes.Items.Cast<string>().Select(x => "." + x);
```

Search ignoring case by enumerating all files in directory:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDIR.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => extensions.Any(y => y.Equals(Path.GetExtension(x), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

As alternative you could search for specified extensions only:

```
 var files = extensions.AsParallel().SelectMany(x => Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDIR.Text, "*" + x, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    items.Add(comboBox1.Items[i].ToString().ToLower());
}

var files = Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(sourceDIR.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(file => items.Any(item => file.ToLower().EndsWith(item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

another possibility, would be to use the search pattern. Unfortunately it is not possible to search for multiple patterns at once. But you could use `SelectMany` to scan through the pattern list and flatten the search results into a single list:

```
var allPatterns = comboFileTypes.Items.Cast<string>();
allPatterns.SelectMany(pattern => Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"F:\temp", $"*.{pattern}", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

The filenames will be ordered as the pattern list