# VB: Search files in a folder and show only Word and PDF files

Tags: vb.net, fileinfo, getfiles

I have problem searching folder and find all files with specific name.
With this method I am able to browse my folder and find all files. But only Word files.

```
Dim fi As FileInfo() = path.GetFiles(fileName & "*.doc*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Now I would like to search **Word** and **PDF**. Is there a way how I can find it?
If I just write a dot instead of .doc it searches the folder but finds all files. Excel, txt etc.

```
Dim fi As FileInfo() = path.GetFiles(fileName & "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

The goal would be to find only certain types of files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Directory.EnumerateFiles with multiple criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/how-to-filter-directory-enumeratefiles-with-multiple-criteria) or [Multiple file-extensions searchPattern for System.IO.Directory.GetFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039580/multiple-file-extensions-searchpattern-for-system-io-directory-getfiles)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use the GetFiles method to enumerate files with multiple extensions. To do that, you'll have to write your own code to do the filtering. I also recommend you use the `EnumerateFiles` method as it provides better performance over the `GetFiles` method in most cases.

Here is sample code to do the filtering as you require

```
Dim filterExtensions = {".docx", ".pdf"}

Dim files = From f In System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Path", "*.*", _
                                                         SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Let fi = New FileInfo(f)
            Where filterExtensions.Contains(fi.Extension.ToLower())
            Select fi
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and create `FileInfo` objects yourself when you could create a `DirectoryInfo` first and call `EnumerateFiles` on that to get ready-made `FileInfo` objects.

Comment: Also, I would tend to use `Where filterExtensions.Any(Function(ext) String.Equals(ext, fi.Extension, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`.

Comment: *"the EnumerateFiles method as it provides better performance over the GetFiles method in most cases"*. If you intend to enumerate the results then yes. If you were going to bind the results or something like that then you need an `IList` anyway, so the array returned by `GetFiles` fits the bill. Otherwise, you'd have to call `ToArray` or the like anyway.